Möbius map and unitary disk.

Find all values $z_{0} \in \mathbb C$ for which the Möbius function $$\varphi(z)=\frac{z-1}{z-z_{0}}$$ send the unitary disk $\Delta =\{z \in \mathbb C : |z|<1\}$ within itself.

First since $0 \in \Delta$ then necessarily $|\varphi (0)| < 1$ which implies that $|\frac{-1}{-z_0}|<1 \Rightarrow 1 < |z_0|$ then a condition about $z_0$ is that $1<|z_0|$. I cant deduce any other condition about $z_0$ i try to find a upper bound for $|z|$, but i have not been successful.
Another approach that is use the characterization of the Möbius maps as compositions of translations, inversions and homothety - rotations.
Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

We begin by establishing a necessary condition. Evaluating $f(z)$ at $z = 0$, which lies in $D$, we find $f(0) = z₀ / 1 = z₀$. For $f$ to map $D$ into itself, we must have $|f(0)| \leq 1$, which implies $|z₀| \leq 1$. However, this condition alone is insufficient.
To derive a more precise condition, we consider the inequality $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in D$. This can be rewritten as $\left|\frac{z + z₀}{1 + z₀z}\right| < 1$, or equivalently, $|z + z₀| < |1 + z₀z|$. Geometrically, this means that for all $z \in D$, the distance from $f(z)$ to $-z₀$ must be less than the distance from $f(z)$ to $-1/\overline{z₀}$.
On the boundary of $D$, where $|z| = 1$, the maximum distance from $z$ to $-z₀$ is $|z₀| + 1$, occurring when $z = -z₀/|z₀|$. The minimum distance from $z$ to $-1/\overline{z₀}$ on this boundary is $||z₀| - 1|/|z₀|$. For the inequality to hold for all $z \in D$, we must have:
$$(|z₀| + 1) \leq \frac{|z₀|² - 1}{|z₀|}$$
This inequality simplifies to $|z₀| \geq 3$. However, we can show that equality is insufficient. When $|z₀| = 3$, there exists some $z \in D$ for which $|f(z)| = 1$, meaning $f$ does not map $D$ strictly into itself.
To establish the strict inequality, we can use a more detailed analysis. The condition for $f$ to map $D$ into itself can be expressed as:
$$\frac{|z₀|² - 1}{||z₀|² - 1|} \geq \frac{2|z₀|}{|z₀|² + 1}$$
This inequality holds if and only if $|z₀| > 3$.
Therefore, we conclude that the Möbius transformation $f(z) = \frac{z + z₀}{1 + z₀z}$ maps the unit disk $D$ strictly into itself if and only if $|z₀| > 3$. In other words, the set of all such z₀ is precisely the exterior of the closed disk centered at the origin with radius 3 in the complex plane.

Ok, i have one question the map $f(z)=\frac{z+z_0}{1+z_{0}z}$ is the same of $\varphi(z)=\frac{z-1}{z-z_0}$ ? because i work with $\varphi$ not with $f$. I still appreciate your help
